# Generate k-combinations with replacement of n-size set using maximum s-number of elements of n-size set (where s<n)

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I know how to get all possible combinations with replacement using itertools, but I want to limit the number of combinations with replacement by using limited number of elements from a larger set.

To give an example, I have a set

`[0,1,2]`

and I want to get k-combinations with replacement (k=4) but using maximum 2 different elements from a set `[0,1,2]`

so sets of elements that can appear in each combination are:

```
[0,1], [1,2], [0,2].
```

Here, I also want to avoid repetition of combinations, so in this example [0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1] or [2,2,2,2] should not duplicate.

The output for this example:

```
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1]
[0,0,1,1]
[0,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,2]
[1,1,2,2]
[1,2,2,2]
[2,2,2,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,2,2]
[0,2,2,2]
```

I hope I am clear.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service. We ask that you provide a [mcve] including what have you tried so far, and what was wrong with your attempt(s)? For example, itertools [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
import itertools

s = [0,1,2]
k = 4
limit = 2

result = set()

for c in itertools.combinations(s, limit):
    result.update(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(c, k))
```

Or with a set comprehension:

```
result = {
    r
    for c in itertools.combinations(s, 2)
    for r in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(c, k)
}
```

Both result in:

```
print(*result, sep="\n")
(0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 2, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Taking the elements of the original list 2 by 2 was just for the sake of the example, the OP wants to do that for any number `s` of items, not just 2.

Comment: The output is probably the one from the first version of your code, it contains duplicates.